# SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end when using send method Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i got `SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end` when I use `send` method to in order to convert the string into object in my Rails application. What's weird is that, it is working find when I am using it to compare the value to something, like this:

```
if @whiteboard.contract.send(user_ast_contract_accept) == true
  ....
end
```

But, when I use it to update the value, I got that error. Below is the full error:

```
    SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
    user.send(user_credit_check) = "Submitted"
                                  ^:
  app/controllers/whiteboards_controller.rb:355:in `'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `constantize'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:72:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `controller'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:41:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
```

Below is my codes, including the functions that i made:

```
def get_member_position(user, contract)
    if user.id == contract.tenant1.to_i
        return "tenant1"
    elsif user.id == contract.tenant2.to_i
        return "tenant2"
    elsif user.id == contract.tenant3.to_i
        return "tenant3"    
    elsif user.id == contract.tenant4.to_i  
        return "tenant4"
    elsif user.id == contract.landlord.to_i 
        return "landlord"
    elsif user.id == contract.guarantor1.to_i   
        return "guarantor1"
    elsif user.id == contract.guarantor2.to_i   
        return "guarantor2"
    elsif user.id == contract.guarantor3.to_i   
        return "guarantor3"
    elsif user.id == contract.guarantor4.to_i   
        return "guarantor4"
    else    
    end
end 

def get_user_credit_check(user, contract)
    member_position = get_member_position(user, contract)
    user_credit_check = member_position + "_credit_check"

    return user_credit_check
end 

contract = Contract.find(params[:contract_id])
user_credit_check = get_user_credit_check(current_user, contract)
contract.send(user_credit_check) = "Submitted"
contract.save
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to assign the string "Submitted" to the result of calling the method, ie. `user.send(user_credit_check)`. That's not quite how it works.

If the variable `user_credit_check` was equal to the string "my_check", and you wanted to call `user.my_check`, then using `send` like this would work.

However, I assume you want to do something like `user.my_check = "Submitted"`, which is actually just Ruby syntactic sugar for `user.my_check=("Submitted")`. So the method you want to pass to `send` is actually "my_check=", not "my_check", and the second argument to `send` is the arguments to pass, ie. "Submitted".

In summary, you want to do something like:

```
user.send("#{user_credit_check}=", "Submitted")
```

As an aside, I would always use `public_send`, not `send` for things like this - I understand that the method in this case is a Rails-provided accessor, but just in case - private methods should stay private, and this is one way of accidentally circumventing that layer of privacy.

Comment: Ah thanks...The error now make sense to me and this solves my problem!